# Unable to suspend laptop

Tags: 20.04, usb, suspend

The laptop does not suspend when suspend key is pressed, it is not suspended even when I type

`command systemctl suspend -i .`

One of the usb ports does not work and `usb2-port3 over-current condition`  message comes at dmesg.

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 ;
- HW: DELL Latitude

The laptop successfully goes to sleep in Windows 10 mode(dual boot).

Following is the journalctl log regarding suspend

```
    May 30 01:34:27 user_abcd kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
    May 30 01:34:33 user_abcd kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
    May 30 01:34:33 user_abcd kernel: PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16
    May 30 01:34:33 user_abcd kernel: PM: Device usb2 failed to suspend async: error -16
    May 30 01:34:33 user_abcd kernel: PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16
    May 30 01:34:33 user_abcd kernel: PM: Device usb1 failed to suspend async: error -16
    May 30 01:34:33 user_abcd kernel: PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
    May 30 01:34:33 user_abcd kernel: PM: suspend exit
    May 30 01:34:33 user_abcd kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
    May 30 01:34:38 user_abcd kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
    May 30 01:34:38 user_abcd kernel: PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16
    May 30 01:34:38 user_abcd kernel: PM: Device usb2 failed to suspend async: error -16
    May 30 01:34:38 user_abcd kernel: PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16
    May 30 01:34:38 user_abcd kernel: PM: Device usb1 failed to suspend async: error -16
    May 30 01:34:38 user_abcd kernel: PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
    May 30 01:34:39 user_abcd kernel: PM: suspend exit
    May 30 01:34:38 user_abcd systemd-sleep[2322]: Failed to suspend system. System resumed again: Device or resource busy
    May 30 01:34:39 user_abcd systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    May 30 01:34:39 user_abcd systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    May 30 01:34:39 user_abcd systemd[1]: suspend.target: Job suspend.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e007 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5769 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please mention which Ubuntu version you are using. And which hardware. Add this information to your question **NOT** into the comments. Open a terminal and type `lsusb`. Copy the answer and add this to your question as well

Comment: The error -16 is "Device Busy". Some process is still using `usb1`, some process is still using `usb2`, and didn't shutdown.

Comment: @waltinator how to find which process are using usb1 and usb2 and how to prevent usb1 and usb2 from being used. And by the way shutdown happens normally without any problems , only suspend and hibernate are not working.

Comment: The same on Fedora. Seems like some Linux kernel bug.

Comment: There is a relevant bug report for xhci_pci kernel module: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=116761. Try `rmmod xhci_pci` before suspend, xhci_pci kernel module can fail to suspend failing overall suspend of the system.